# CSS, position absolute, plus extra pixels

Tags: css

the title might be confusing, but let me try to explain.
I have a few objects on my website, all with id's in the style section with fixed position (position:absolute, left and top etc).

(I tried to add style sheet code, but this page didn't let me post it, so use your imagination)

Now I want to add a little icon (flag) underneath all the objects, about 20-25 pixel below the above positions. How can I do that?

Comment: You should provide some code ! we see only code here !

Comment: Yes, code would be helpful. Sounds like you may want to use a `::before` or `::after` element. Assuming your icon is from an icon font, you will need to reference it in the content attribute using something like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Comment: You could potentially use something like `img { position: relative; top: -25px; }` or something of the likes, but without context it's hard to give a proper answer. If you need help posting code, you can check out the [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/); additionally, you could just copy-paste a snippet and the community can edit the post to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrap** the objects in divs, provide **absolute position to the wrapper div**, add your icon in the div.

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper'>

        <img src='' class='image your-object'>
        <i class="icon"><!-- ICON HERE --></i>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
   position: absolute;
   top: 5%;
   left: 5%;
   // your css here
}

.icon{
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I figured out myself earlier today. Previously, the IDs were give to 14 different form input fields that were spread across the page. Now I just give the IDs to divs, which have the input fields in it. Simple solution, but when I came up with the idea of the icon first, that didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Browser take out the elements with position fixed or absolute from the normal flow of the page. so you need to assign an id or class to your icon and style it manually (with hard code top/left position in pixels) in your stylesheet. However if you are comfortable with javascript or jquery then it is possible to calculate the top/left position of those elements and dynamically assign top/left position to your icon...